# String.equals() won't work

Tags: java, android

My problem is that this won't work:

```
if (result.equals("success")) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.myContext, "Hausaufgabe eingetragen!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    startSync(lv);
}
else if (result.equals("already exists")) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.myContext, "Hausaufgabe wurde bereits eingetragen!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else if (result.equals("user not exists")){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.myContext, "Das eingespeicherte Benutzerkonto ist ungültig oder gelöscht worden!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else if (result.equals("server problem")){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.myContext, "Ein Server Problem ist aufgetreten!\n" + "Bitte melden!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.myContext, "Unbekannte Rückmeldung des Servers:\n" + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

Log.d("API",result);
```

LogCat says API:success, but feedback in the app is "Unbekannte Rückmeldung des Servers:
                                                     success"

Comment: Did you make sure the value is trimmed? In other words, no whitespace around the string?

Comment: also equals is case sensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `trim()` method, because your variable `result` probably contains an space, like " success":

```
if (result.trim().equals("success")) {
...
...
```

you could complement with `toLowerCase()` method, to prevent the handle of capitalized letters like " Success":

```
 if (result.trim().toLowerCase().equals("success")) {
    ...
    ...
```

or try using `indexOf()` method

for example:

```
if (result.indexOf("success") > 0) {
...
...
```

Comment: index of worked for me! Thank you! But i have a question: why doesn't it work with equals or trim, my browsers show the api correctly?

Comment: Mr Androider if your variable "result" has de value of "success", using equals must be enough; if your variable "result" has de value of " success ", "success " or " success " .trim().equals() will do the job; check if the variable "result" really has the value of "success", probably has for example "is´t a success", the trim().equals() doesn´t work here.

Comment: My browsers told me "succcess", Logcat told me "success", Toast told me " success"?